# SSL Error - Cannot Browse an HTTPS Address

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, ssl, trusted-root-certificates

In one of my computers I can not browse https://www.stackoverflow.com and both chrome and IE show SSL error page to me, while on the other computer I can successfully browse the site.

The strange thing to me is:

1. The certificate information on those two systems are different. (Screenshot of general information of those certificates is at the end of this post).
2. The result of `ping stackoverflow.com` on those systems is different. On the system which successfully brows https the ping ip is `151.101.129.69` and on the non-working system is `104.16.36.249`. The dns settings of both systems are on `Obtain DNS server automatically`.
3. All other https sites like google, bing and so on could be successfully browsed.

I've tried these things to fix the problem without any success:

- I exported the certificate of the system which could browse https stackoverflow successfully and installed it on the other system in Trusted Root Certificates but it doesn't fixed the problem.
- I deleted history of browser, but it doesn't fix the problem.
- I updated Widows. (The OS of non-working system is Windows 8.1)
- I checked system date and time in both systems and date and time is OK and the same.

How can I fix the problem?

**PS:**

- Here is the [certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjy2v.png) of the system which shows error when browsing https stackoverflow.
- Here is the [certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHUu1.png) of the system which can successfully browse https stackoverflow:

Comment: @thilinaR I think it's a Windows/Browser problem and not related to Stackoverflow itself, So I posted it here.

Comment: This is a problem with your configuration.  Verify you https connections are not being scanned.  Verify you are not connected to a proxy.  You should try Firefox, it uses its own certificate store, if it works then you know something is being done to secure connections but only effects Chrome and IE.

Comment: @Ramhound I have a NextVPN software installed on both systems. But when browsing https://stackoverflow.com neither of those systems are connected to VPN. The strange thing is different SSL certificate which browser shows on those two systems.

Comment: Does the same thing happen with other `https` sites?

Comment: @thilinaR No, google or bing or some other sites are OK.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - Have you tried my other suggestion?  Have you tried without the VPN?  All I can say is that the fact the incorrect certificate is only valid for a year, indicates its purpose, is to scan https traffi.

Comment: ping stackoverflow.com from both computers and see if it resolves to the same address. If they resolve to a different address. This is what i get: https://i.imgur.com/8GKVoyu.png

Comment: @thilinaR The result of `ping stackoverflow.com` on those systems is different. On the system which successfully brows https the ping ip is `151.101.129.69` and on the non-working system is `104.16.36.249`. The dns settings of both systems are on `Obtain DNS server automatically`.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not behind a VPN on those systems. But the result of `ping stackoverflow.com` are different in those systems as I said in above comment.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - The information isn't in the question so i missed it.  So have you confirmed, the DNS servers being used by both machines, are identical?  You should update your question to include all new and old relevant information.  This is so the comment section can be cleaned up.  *You should go ahead, and change the DNS server on both machines to the exact samething, something other then "btain DNS server automatically" though.*

Comment: Good, the fact that stackoverflow.com resolves to a different address is why you are not able to browse it on the problematic PC. (1) Clear your DNS cache. (2) Please make sure that there are no static entries on the hosts file. (3) And make sure there isn't any software (including malware) that would interfere with the name resolution process.

Comment: @Ramhound I updated the question. I also tried `Obtain DNS server automatically` and flushing dns without success.

Comment: @thilinaR That's it. the host file was the problem! I had an entry in the file using `104.16.36.249` as IP. I removed it and it solved the problem.

Comment: sounds good. posted as an answer :)

Comment: @thilinaR I wonder how could I forgot about host which I'd changed it manually for resolution speed. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for your help, I solved the issue by looking in `host` file and I saw I'd added some manual entry for the site to speed up name resolution. I removed those entries and the problem got fixed.

Comment: @thilinaR I made the question title more general to not seems specific to stackoverflow and be more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ping the URL from both computers and see if it resolves to the same address.

For example:

[image: ping stackoverflow.com]

If they are different on both PCs, try the following:

1. Make sure the DNS settings are the same on both PCs.
2. Clear your DNS cache.
3. Please make sure that there are no static entries on the [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) referencing this URL.
4. And make sure there isn't any software (including malware) that would interfere with the name resolution process.

Answer (score 0):

it can be something wrong with your DNS, I've seen that some ADSL providers have problems on DNS servers. check this out:

first manually set your DNS servers to something trusted like 8.8.8.8 and 4.2.2.4

after that run flushdns in command prompt

and finally refresh the page without using browser cache. (Ctrl + F5)

I hope it would help!

Comment: I'll check it, but both systems are behind the same wireless modem.

Comment: I checked `4.2.2.4` and `8.8.8.8` and also `Obtain DNS server automatically`. Also run `ipconfig /flushdns` and used Ctrl + F5. Without success. It may be a DNS problem because the result of `ping stackoverflow.com` is different on those systems. But It didn't got fixed by changing DNS servers and flushing dns. Any Idea?